# How to use point-kinetics approximation to go from diffusion to point kinetics?

Tags: nuclear-physics, diffusion, neutrons, nuclear-engineering

I understand that we get to point kinetics by neglecting spatial dependence in the diffusion equation, but I'm somewhat stuck on the details here. Robert E. Masterson's [Introduction to Nuclear Reactor Physics](https://books.google.dk/books/about/Introduction_to_Nuclear_Reactor_Physics.html?id=ZjwPEAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y), expresses the time-dependent neutron diffusion equation with delayed neutrons as eq. (15.13)

$
\frac{1}{v} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = D \nabla^2 \phi + ((1-\beta) v \Sigma_f - \Sigma_a) \phi(\mathbf{r},t) + S(\mathbf{r},t)
$

where the source term is split between prompt and delayed sources, i.e. $S(\mathbf{r},t) = S_p(\mathbf{r},t) + S_d(\mathbf{r},t) = S_p(\mathbf{r},t) + \lambda C(\mathbf{r},t)$. Eq. 15.14 tells us that the point-kinetics approximation is

$\phi(\mathbf{r},t) = \phi(\mathbf{r}) \phi(t)$

inserting into our diffusion equation, and assuming no external sources of prompt neutrons, yields

$
\frac{1}{v} \phi(r) \frac{d \phi}{d t} = D \phi(t) \nabla^2 \phi(\mathbf{r}) + ((1-\beta) v \Sigma_f - \Sigma_a) \phi(\mathbf{r}) \phi(t) + \lambda C(t) 
$

Here's where I'm stuck, if you simply remove $\phi(r)$, you end up with point-kinetics, but $\phi(r)$ does not cancel on its own. Do we just assume that it is some constant that we can arbitrarily set to one? Is there some hand waving to justify that? If not, have I made an error somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also apply the point-kinetics approximation to the precursor concentration $C(\boldsymbol{r}, t)$ as
\begin{equation}
C(\boldsymbol{r},t) = C(t)\phi(\boldsymbol{r}) \,,
\end{equation}
where, according to yout notation, $\phi(\boldsymbol{r})$ should indicate the fundamental mode (or eigenfunction) of the neutron flux. By doing so you can eliminate the spatial dependence and you end up with the PK model. You can look at *Nuclear Reactor Analysis*, Chapter 6 by Duderstadt and Hamilton for more references .

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you.